# Selenium to throw error if value entered is more or less than the allowed limit

Tags: java, selenium

What would be the best code for such problem, i need to make sure the values enter count is not less than 3 and not more than 250, if user enters less than 3 or more than 250 characters the test should keep going but printout error saying (test failed word count exceeded/less than minimum)

my code

public void enteringtask(String values){

```
    if(values == String.valueOf(2));
    return "needs to be 3";

    enterTask.sendKeys(values);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Does the user have to enter a number between 3 and 250, or does the user have to enter a string of at lease 3 characters but not more than 250 characters? Also, never use == to compare the content of two Strings; you need to use the equals() method.

Comment: the user has to enter characters between 3 and 250 for it to be valid

Answer (score 0):

Without proper assertion library it's hard to tell but this is a simple way to make it work in selenium. You should put the test codes in between if's

```
public void checkBetween(String mystring){
        try{
            if (mystring.length()>3 || mystring.length()< 251 ){
                System.out.println("mystring is between 3 to 250 char");
                //Put your code for test with Assertion here


                }
            else{

                //Failing by default if string length is less than 3 or greater than 250
                Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
                }
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
```